# Why isnt my loop completing the print function

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Im new to python can anyone please exsplain why my code isnt working all that happens when i run it is it prits out the numbers even when it prints a 10 it wont print done please help

```
while True:
    a = 10
    from random import seed
    from random import randint
    seed(1)
    for _ in range(10):
            b = randint(0, 10)
            print(b)
    if b == a:
        print('done')    
  
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: What is the point of `seed(1)`? You're always going to generate the same values each iteration. Why are you importing within the loop?

Comment: `b == a` only checks if the last number generated is equal to 10 - which it will never be (given that you set a fixed seed).

Comment: It will only print `done` if `b == a`, based on the value of `b` at the *last* iteration of the loop.  If your numbers were truly random, we should only expect `b == a` in one out of eleven runs.  But as @SuperStormer points out, the fixed seed means that you effectively *aren't* using random numbers, but rather the same series of numbers in each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think about the logic of the code. Is `if b == a:` inside the `for` loop, or outside? (How do you know?) Therefore, when will it be checked - every time through the `for` loop, or only after the `for` loop finishes? After the `for` loop finishes, what is the value of `b`? Do you see why this causes a problem? Before asking on Stack Overflow, please try to [find simple logical problems yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by carefully tracing what happens when the code runs.

Comment: Also: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We are not interested in your level of experience, and "please help" [is not actionable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). We are **only** interested in *clear, specific* questions. Try to organize your thoughts into complete English sentences, and then ask, using a **question** that starts with a question word like "why" or "how" and ends with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 0):

*Okay so based on the code and the explanation given, I assume that you want the above script to generate a set of numbers randomly until a 10 gets printed. Once a 10 is printed you want to the program to stop.*

For that you need to do something like this:

```
from random import seed
from random import randint

seed(1)

break_value = 10
b = 0

# The loop runs until b hits the designated break value (10)
while (b != break_value):
    # Every loop a new b value is generated and output
    b = randint(0, 10)
    print(b)

# After the while loop terminates, we print done
print("done")
```

Output:

```
2
9
1
4
1
7
7
7
10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just have to use a post condition while loop so when val =10 it breaks. Also, the print("done") should be outside the loop so as to avoid repetition

```
import random as r #imported module
x = True 
stop_value = 10 #target value
while x:
    val = r.randint(1,10)
    print(val)
    if val == stop_value:
        x = False #this break the while loop when val = target value
print("done")
```